# Friction between two stacked blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction

I was studying friction when I came across a question in my book, A block of mass 2kg is stacked on top of a block of mass 4kg. A force of 20N is acting at an angle of 37 degrees on the system. Find the accelerations of both the blocks if it is known that the coefficients of static and kinetic friction between the two blocks are 0.3 and 0.2 respectively and there is no friction between the ground and the 4kg block.

I started by calculating the acceleration of the lower block (caused by friction) when I got confused so as to take 0.3 or 0.2 (static or kinetic) as the coefficient of the frictional force pushing the lower block.

Can someone pls throw some light on this......

Comment: Upon which block is the 20N force acting? And is the angle with the horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that there is no slipping between the blocks and try finding the value of static friction, if it is more than limiting value of static friction then blocks will slip and kinetic friction would act.

Comment: Thank you, I understood, the answer is also coming correct